# Option created dynamically don't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, createelement

I'm working on a form, with selects created dynamically. So I did this:

```
function populateSelect() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: URLSELECT + 'tipologia',
    success: function (response) {
      let key;
      for (var k in response._embedded) {
        key=k;
        break
      }
      createSelect(response._embedded[key], "tipologia")
      let options = $('select[name=tipologia]').find('option');
      options.each((el)=>{
        $(this).on('click', function(){
          console.log($(this));
        })
      })
    },
    error: function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}

function createSelect(options, select) {

 options.forEach((el)=>{
  let text = el.name;
  let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.setAttribute('value', text);
      option.textContent = text
      option.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        console.log('test);
        
      }) 
  document.querySelector(`[name=${select}]`).appendChild(option);
 })
}
```

Now if I inspect the HTML the option are created in right way, with the right value and right text, but the addEventListener is not working.

Comment: As far as I remember `option` does not support click event. You had to use `onchange`  on the `select`.

Comment: `response._embedded[0]` would be simpler and faster than all the `let key;` and `for` loop logic. `key` will always be equal to `0` anyway after the 1-cycle loop.

Comment: @JeremyThille i tried but he return me an error, so i found this fix

Comment: @Lain thanks lain i'll try ;)

Comment: `response._embedded.shift()` then?

Comment: nope. he say is not a function...because response._embedded is an object anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the `click` event is not well supported on `option` elements. The far better practice is to listen for the `change` event on the parent `select`, then read the value of the chosen `option`.

Also, your code is a lot more complex than it needs to be. You can more easily build the list of `option` elements from the response of the AJAX request using `map()` and `append()`. Try this:

```js
let $select = $('select[name=tipologia]').on('change', e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});

function populateSelect() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: URLSELECT + 'tipologia',
    success: function(response) {
      let options = response._embedded.map(o => `<option value="${o.name}">${o.name}</option>`);
      $select.html(options);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```